# How to select row numbers and then categorizing them in a new column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a new column that categorizes each tweet as "finals" or "shopping".  I know which row numbers for each one (0-1993 is "finals" and 1994-4070 is "shopping").  I tried doing this

```
stress_df['Finals_or_Shopping'] = stress_df.index[0:1952] = 'finals'
```

but then I get an error of "TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations" and it adds a column but each row has "finals" in it.

Any tips would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it with `numpy.where`, assuming everything with index below/equal to the `row_cutoff` needs to be labelled "finals" and everything else as "shopping":

```
import numpy as np
row_cutoff = 1993 
df["Finals_or_Shopping"] = np.where(df.index <= row_cutoff, "finals", "shopping")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use loc or iloc

```
stress_df['Finals_or_Shopping']="finals" 
stress_df.loc[1994:,'Finals_or_Shopping']="shopping"
```